# Build failed at the end

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry for this question, but i don't know how resolve this error. This is my Console after i try to build the application. Sorry for my english. I hope can you help me, and i use the Unity 2019.3.7f1 (64 bit)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users*******\Desktop\Universit� (2019-2020)\2� Semestre\Mobile Computing\progetti Unity\Project\UniversityProject\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >
  > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is in a folder, which contains non ASCII characters (simplifying, any character which is not A-Z or numbers). You probably used some special characters in the folder names (they show up as "�" in your question). Move your project to another folder, or change the names which contain special characters and it should build.